# Ordering of routes using annotations

Tags: symfony

The usual solution when you create routes in symfony and you want to have one route like

```
/{username}
```

so that it does not conflict with other routes like /login or /info is just to put that route as your last route in your routing.yml file. Since all the other routes take precedence this conflict is avoided. But how can you do this if you define your routes as annotations in your controllers? Is there any way to specify the ordering of this routes in this case?

Comment: Hi Carlos, but what happen if one user is registered with login username ? then there are a two routes equals. Could you resolve it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the context of a controller, the order of action methods defines the order of routes. In the context of the whole application, you can import each controller explicitly to control the order, for example:

```
Home:
    resource: "\Vendor\Controller\HomeController"
    type: annotation

Security:
    resource: "\Vendor\Controller\SecurityController"
    type: annotation

security.log_out:
    pattern: "/logout"

User:
    resource: "\Vendor\Controller\UserController"
    type: annotation
```

Comment: I found that this is currently (Symfony 2.4) working only with complete Controller filename. So, `HomeController.php` and not simply `HomeController`

Comment: @MassimilianoArione, these are namspaces — not paths to files. If namespaces don't work for you, you're doing something wrong. It works great for me in both 2.4 and 2.5.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation

Comment: In symfony 4, it's not needed to specify all controllers. First, specify the controllers as documented on https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html . The controller that must be added later, put it add the end in 'routes/annotations.yaml'. Notation as given in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the answer, so I will leave how I had to write it in Symfony 2.3 to get it to work:

```
Home:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Controller/HomeController.php"
    prefix: /home #optional
    type: annotation
```

Notice the change of "\" to "/" and using .php at the end of controller name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the rule for that route at the end of your routing.yml. You can do this by using the same name for the route as the one that is automatically created by the annotation. You can find the name with the console command:

```
php app/console debug:router
```

So in your routing.yml as the last line you will add:

```
the_name_of_the_route_as_found_with_appconsole_debug_router:
    path:/{username}
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:the_action_to_use }
```

By using the same name it is given by default you will override the original. Don't forget other options that might be important. Like a default value or null for {username} or the method.

You could also remove completely the route from the annotation for the controller. It is not required anymore as it is overwritten anyway :)