# Symfony2 - Can't figure out why my search function is having an error on my show page

Tags: symfony, search

I am implementing a simple search function that I've used on other projects without any problems. For some reason it's giving me an error on my showAction - 'Show page' that I can't figure out why.

`Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a NULL variable ("") in AcmeBundle:Blog:show.html.twig at line 9`

I've done a dump on my $blog variable in showAction (which gives me the the error above - if I do not comment out the if statement I get the NotFoundException in my showAction(). My search code doesn't even go to any show action or template.

My blog entity is has a ManyToMany relationship to one entity and a ManyToOne on another, not sure if this is messing up my search code?

**Question: I'm at a loss to why the search function is going to my showAction and why it's coming up null?**

**showAction()**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slug}", name="AcmeBundle_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("AcmeBundle:Blog:show.html.twig")
 */
public function showAction($slug)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$blog = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Blog')->findOneBy(array(
    'slug' => $slug
));
var_dump($blog);

if (!$blog) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find blog post');
}

return array(
    'blog' => $blog,
    'slug' => $slug,
);
}
```

**Search code** as a service

```
public function search()
{
    $results = null;
    $query = $this->request->query->get('q');

    if (!empty($query)) {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

        $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('AcmeBundle:Blog', 'b')
            ->select('b')
            ->where('b.title LIKE :search')
            ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('search', "%${query}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    return array(
        'query'   => $query,
        'results' => $results,
    );
```

Controller with searchAction

```
/**
 * @Route("/search", name="AcmeBundle_search")
 * @Template("AcmeBundle:Page:search.html.twig")
 */
public function searchAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // Search code: calling from the service Search
    $query = $this->get('search');

    $results = $query->search();

    $recentBlogLimit = $this->container->getParameter('acme.latest.blogs_limit');

    $latestBlogs = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Blog')
        ->getBlogs($recentBlogLimit);

    $tags = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Tag')
        ->getTags();

    return array(
        'query'        => $query,
        'results'      => $results['results'],
        'latestBlogs'  => $latestBlogs,
        'tags'         => $tags,
    );
}
```

Search code on twig

```
<section class="section">
    <form action="{{ path('AcmeBundle_search') }}" method="GET">
    <label><input type="search" name="q" value={{ app.request.query.get('q') }}></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: My guess would be a routing conflict. Both `/{slug}` and `/search` are too ambiguous. You should try and have your `/search` route registered first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759057/ordering-of-routes-using-annotations

Comment: @Phil You're absolutely RIGHT, changed my show route to /{id}/{slug} and it worked perfectly. Can you put your reply as an answer so I can accept it? Also, how can I register /search first when they are on different controllers as annotations?

Comment: @Phil - Ok I see how to order it.

Comment: It's similar enough to that other question to close as duplicate. Upvote the question and answer over there to show your appreciation :)

Comment: Will do. Cheers Phil.