# Slugs causing route conflicts

Tags: symfony, slug

I have an action in my PostController that is displaying all the posts on the main page having a slug as  an argument.

**PostController:displayAction**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{postSlug}", defaults={"postSlug"= false})
 * @Template()
 */
 public function displayAction($postSlug)
 {
     //Forget about whats inside here
     return array[];
 }
```

Now i have another controller for Users having a login action and for that i am setting /login as route in Route annotation

**UserController:loginAction**

```
/**
 * @Route("/login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    //bla bla bla
    return [];
}
```

Now the issue is that when ever i try to access localhost:8000/login, it shows me a white page and the controller and action on the debug tool bar is PostController:DisplayAction where as it should be UserController::loginAction. The reason i believe is that it is causing some conflicts with the slug but i can defend my stance here by saying that i have another controller "CreatePostController" having Route annotation "/create" which works fine, i am not sure why but it works.

I am sure i am doing some mistake but do not know what and if there is a conflict then how can CreatePostController work?

**Router:Debug Screenshot**
[image: Router:Debug]

**Routing.yml**

```
blogger_blog_homepage:
resource: "@BloggerBlogBundle/Controller"
type: annotation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with routing. If you have route declaration for /{postSlug} before /login route, then it will access /{postSlug} before /login, because login is matching postSlug too. System doesn't know that login is not postSlug.

You can avoid that by putting /login route before /{postSlug} route. Check your routing.yml file.

Because you are using annotation for routing, you have to be carefull, because Symfony uses some priorities.

Break down your routing.yml into:

```
blogger_blog_user:
resource: "@BloggerBlogBundle/Controller/UserController.php"
type:     annotation

blogger_blog_homepage:
resource: "@BloggerBlogBundle/Controller/PostController.php"
type:     annotation
```

And the same for CreatePostController. UserController must be before other controllers.

Comment: I am not using routing.yml any how - i am just using annotations and secondly why CreatePostList:createAction is working?

Keep in mind all of them are in separate controllers

Comment: Can you please post app/config/routing.yml file? And also $ php app/console router:debug

Comment: I have updated the post, please have a look at the screenshop and routing.yml

Comment: @OsamaYawar This answer is correct, but you're just not listening to him. Without explicitly ordering the references to the Controller annotated routes, it will just load the routes as it loads the Controllers... in alphabetical order! [See this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759057/ordering-of-routes-using-annotations). +1 for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add requirmens parameter, for example, if you postSlug have only numbers:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{postSlug}", defaults={"postSlug"= false}, requirements={"postSlug"="\d+"})
 * @Template()
 */
 public function displayAction($postSlug)
 {
     //Forget about whats inside here
     return array[];
 }
```