# Routing order symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have a url with a wildcard at the end `site.com/{username}` after trying to match url's like `site.com/photos` and `site.com/blog`. I'm using annotations and have two controllers.

I found an answer here [Ordering of routes using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759057/ordering-of-routes-using-annotations)

But the folder structure is different in version 4 and in the answer they are using YAML while I'm using annotations, so I don't fully understand where to put what.

**Video Controller**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/videos", name="videos")
     */
    public function index()
    {
      // Show video homepage
    }
```

**User Controller**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{username}", name="profile")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Hello {username} !
    }
```

In this order, `site.com/videos` reaches User controller instead of videos. Do I have to switch to manually putting *all* URL structures in yaml format or is there a way to set priority in annotations?

So far the only method I found was to create a controller starting with the letter "Z", and putting the action/route in there, that seems to run the route last.

Comment: There is no magical behind the scene, The routing catch the first path found. This comportement is well known  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18415 As you said you have to get a clue and rename your Controller. It’s « Dirty » and strange but it works like a charm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you linked to is actually very relevant. You are asking just the same as the other guy:

> But how can you do this if you define your routes as annotations in your controllers? Is there any way to specify the ordering of this routes in this case?

In Symfony 4, your `config/routes.yaml` is probably empty and `config/routes/annotations.yaml` probably like this:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

You can replace the above YAML with this – notice that the order does matter:

```
Video:
    resource: App\Controller\VideoController
    type: annotation

User:
    resource: App\Controller\UserController
    type: annotation
```

Then `site.com/videos` reaches the video controller first.

Comment: That means every single controller will now need to be declared in `config/routes.yaml` right?

Comment: @Link14, I haven't worked with Symfony in a while, but I would think so. It should be easy to test by omitting a controller from `config/routes.yaml` and testing whether the controller's routes work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your routes with `yml`/`xml` to be able to fully configure their order.
If you really want to use annotation you could add a prefix like `user-`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user-{username}", name="profile")
 */
public function index()
{
    // Hello {username} !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With current(6.2) version of Symfony you can (re)define route priority.
Example from docs:

```php
#[Route('/blog/list', name: 'blog_list', priority: 2)]
```

Bigger value, higher priority.

In your case it would be:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/videos", name="videos", priority: 2)
     */
    public function index()
    {
      // Show video homepage
    }
```

See [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/routing.html#priority-parameter).